# Listar anos em JCombobox dinamicamente a partir de determinada regra

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Tenho uma aplicação que lista registros em uma `JTable`, e cada registro possui data de cadastro usando `Date`.

Nessa lista, coloquei um filtro por ano via `JCombobox`, onde o ano inicial é o que a aplicação começou a ser usada(2013), até 5 anos após o ano atual, como pode ser visto no print:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Essa lista é instanciada por esta linha:

```
//Atributo iniciado direto do JFrame
public static final Integer[] listadeAno = {2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020};

...
//listaAno é o nome do JComboBox do JFrame, nesse instante ele já foi instanciado
this.listaAno = new JComboBox(ListaDeOficiosUI.listadeAno);
```

Minha dúvida é como tornar a geração dessa lista dinâmica, e criar um `ArrayList` de `Integer` que armazene uma lista de anos, onde o primeiro obrigatoriamente seja 2013, até 5 anos a mais que o atual?

Eu criei esse código pra fazer isso, mas gostaria de saber se há como otimizar isso, de preferência sem usar laço de repetição, se possivel.

```
//mudei o tipo do atributo para ArrayList
 public static final ArrayList<Integer> listadeAno = new ArrayList<>();
...
public static void setListaDeAnos() {
    //lista de ano dinâmica conforme o ano atual + 5
    int anoAtual = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
    for (int i = 0; 2013 + i <= anoAtual + 5; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            ListaDeOficiosUI.listadeAno.add(2013);
        } else {
            ListaDeOficiosUI.listadeAno.add(2013 + i);
        }
    }
}
```

**Obs.:** O filtro funciona normalmente, minha dúvida é apenas em relação a criação dinâmica dessa lista pra popular o `JCombobox`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como alternativa, você criar uma classe que te forneça uma sequência baseando-se no elementos que passar por parâmetro para ela.

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Range implements Iterable<Integer> {
    private int min;
    private int count;

    public Range(int min, int count) {
        this.min = min;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<Integer>() {
            private int cur = min;
            private int count = Range.this.count;
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return count != 0;
            }

            public Integer next() {
                count--;
                return cur++; // first return the cur, then increase it.
            }

            public void remove() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

O uso ficaria assim:

```
public static void setListaDeAnos() {
    int anoAtual = LocalDate.now().getYear();
    ListaDeOficiosUI.listadeAno = new Range(2013, (anoAtual - 2013) + 6)
}
```

Retirado [dessa resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9627911/4190610)

---

De qualquer maneira, eu acho que da forma que você está fazendo atualmente está bom e você não tem motivo para tentar mudar. A única dica que eu te daria é remover aquele `if` dentro do `for`, porque aquilo é prolixo.

```
for (int i = 0; 2013 + i <= anoAtual + 5; i++) {
    ListaDeOficiosUI.listadeAno.add(2013 + i);        
}
```

Comment: No fim, acabei usando essa versão com `for` mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

Se sua preferência é sempre dois anos antes, atual e mais cinco anos depois, uma solução como essa, penso que resolveria.

```
public static List<Integer> listaDeAnos() {
    int anoAtual = LocalDate.now().getYear();
    return Arrays.asList(anoAtual - 2, anoAtual - 1, anoAtual, 
            anoAtual + 1, anoAtual + 2, anoAtual + 3, anoAtual + 4, anoAtual + 5);
}
```

Editado

> Com isso, deve ser possivel gerar o que precisa.

```
public static List<Integer> listaDeAnos() {
    List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    int anoAtual = LocalDate.now().getYear();

    lista.add(anoAtual);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        lista.add(anoAtual + i);
    }
    while (anoAtual != 2013) {
        lista.add(0, --anoAtual);
    }
    return lista;
}
```

Comment: A regra seria iniciar a partir de 2013 até 5 anos após o ano atual. Tem que ser 2013 porque é o ano marco.

Comment: Editei o post, verifique :)